# Cannot connect Remote MSSQL through sql alchemy in Mac

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:password@ipaddress.domain.name/database')

con = engine.connect()
```

It is throwing me an error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000]
>   [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Can any one please help me on this ?

Comment: I tried connecting through pyodbc aswell, but I wasnot able to. Does it has to do anything with database configuration

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below settings and try

1) Search for a file named libsqlncli* in your filesystem .Then check its :

A)permissions
B) rows reporting "NOT FOUND" in the output of the ldd command executed against this file;
C )If all seems to be ok check for/ddd the following entry in your odncinst.ini file:

```
*
```

> [SQL Server Native Client 1[0|1].0]  Description=Microsoft SQL Server
>   ODBC Driver V1.0 for Linux
>   Driver=/opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0 
>   UsageCount=1

*

Comment: Similar solution is given in this link as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747635/how-to-connect-to-windows-sql-server-from-ubuntu